# Display date from Date Dimension in SSIS Derived Column

Tags: date, ssis, dimension, derived-column

I created a derived column to include a Fiscal Year in an ssis package. The package includes a DateDimension with a FiscalYear column. The data in the column is displayed as “SFY2018Q1”. The Column name is displayed as “[[$DATE_DIM].[FQUARTER]]

The expression I created should display only the year “2018” from the DateDimension. However, is not resolving “is red” in the derived column. Below is the expression I created.

```
LEFT(RIGHT([$Date_DimFQuarter],3),2)
```

I also attempted the expression by excluding the “$”, and by adding the Table name DateDim. Neither of those modifications work.

Any assistance on what I am doing wrong is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does this mean?   " is not resolving “is red” in the derived column"?  Where do you see "is red"?

Comment: When the expression is entered and does not resolve, the expression text is red.

Answer (score 0):

just double click `derived column toolbox` then drag and drop your column from columns tree, your expression must be `LEFT(RIGHT([YourColumn],3),2)`.
so try not to write the column by your self, just drag and drop it.

Comment: I attempted that before I tried to manually excluding the "$" and including the table name "DateDim".